# How do I add a variable (string) - to an existing object?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object

```
this.ui.list
this.ui.grid
```

These points to a Node element on the DOM already

At the moment, I have two buttons, 'Grid', 'List'.  Grid has a class Active by default, and List doesn't. I have a click event listener on both, and when you click on Grid, it should remove the class Active, and add it to the other sibling, List.

ex. If clicked on grid

```
let siblingElement = utils.js.func.siblings(el.target), // list node
    siblingStyle = siblingElement[0].dataset.style, // outputs: list
    currentElement = el.target, // grid node
    currentStyle = el.target.dataset.style // outputs: grid


classes.remove(siblingElement[0], 'active')
classes.add(el.target, 'active')
```

This works fine, now what I have to do is fade in/out the dom elements that displays the list/grid.

Since when I click on grid for example, I can get the word list by checking the sibling data attribute, I wanted to dynamically use these below to avoid copy/paste, and avoid using if/else/switch

```
tl.to(this.ui.grid, 0.7, { autoAlpha: 0, display: 'none', ease: Expo.easeInOut })
tl.to(this.ui.list, 0.7, { autoAlpha: 1, display: 'block', ease: Expo.easeInout })
```

Since I can get the current style, and the sibling style....'list', 'grid', how would it be able to replace this.ui.grid, this.ui.list with the variables I set above? I hope this isn't confusing, but basically something like this ( I know this does not work )

```
tl.to(this.ui.[siblingStyle], 0.7, { autoAlpha: 0, display: 'none', ease: Expo.easeInOut })
tl.to(this.ui.[currentStyle], 0.7, { autoAlpha: 1, display: 'block', ease: Expo.easeInout })
```

Is this even possible with Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

So, after some thinking....I finally just decided to go with this solution.  If there is something better, please let me know.

```
var choices = {
    "list" : this.ui.grid,
    "grid" : this.ui.list
}

// Fade Effect
tl.to(choices[currentStyle], 0.7, { autoAlpha: 0, display: 'none', ease: Expo.easeInOut })
tl.to(choices[siblingStyle], 0.7, { autoAlpha: 1, display: 'block', ease: Expo.easeInout })
```